# Sharepoint site template : How to pass person data?

Tags: 2013, site-template, template, person

I've create a template site in which I have a list, in this list I have 5 columns with data, one of them is Person or group type, but when I create a new site with this template, all columns are populated except the one with my person/Group, this one stays totally empty

any idea of the reason?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Where are you creating the site using site template? Subsite under the same site? Site under the same site collection? Or somewhere else? Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: I use Sharepoint server 2013
The site template and the template are use at the same level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **Known** behavior in SharePoint.

> Most of the objects in a site are included and supported by the template. However, there are several objects and features that are not supported.
>
> **Supported**: Lists, libraries, external lists, data source connections, list views and data views, custom forms, workflows, content types, custom actions, navigation, site pages, master pages, modules, and web templates.
>
> **Unsupported**: Customized permissions, running workflow instances, list item version history, workflow tasks associated with running workflows, **people or group field values**, taxonomy field values, publishing pages and publishing sites, My Sites, stapled features, SharePoint Add-ins, and remote event receivers.

You can read more about SharePoint site templates in below article:

[What gets saved in a template?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/save-download-and-upload-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template#what-gets-saved-in-a-template)

Answer (score 1):

Person or Group field points to a user information list located on the same site collection. If you transfer a list to another site, you'll lose all connections since the data in user information list in another site collection differs from the original one. Here, I'd recommend migrating data programmatically with REST or CSOM api.

Comment: It's under project server 2013, so my two sites are at the same level so I shouldn't lose my connection no?
No other solution than deploy a csom solution?